# Google Tag Manager - Tag Configuration - appending <script> content within <script>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to include two <script> tags just before the </body> element via a custom tag in Google Tag Manager:

`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cookieconsent@3/build/cookieconsent.min.js" data-cfasync="false"></script>`

and

`<script>window.cookieconsent.initialise({"palette":{"popup":{"background":"#000"},"button":{"background":"#f1d600"}}});</script>`

Because I need them to show up just before the </body> element, I am using jQuery to append these values as strings via appendTo():

```
<script>

var cookieConsentStyles = '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cookieconsent@3/build/cookieconsent.min.css" />';
var cookieConsentJS = '<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cookieconsent@3/build/cookieconsent.min.js" data-cfasync="false"></script>';
var cookieConsentInit = '<script>window.cookieconsent.initialise({"palette":{"popup":{"background":"#000"},"button":{"background":"#f1d600"}}});</script>';

jQuery(cookieConsentStyles).appendTo('head');
jQuery(cookieConsentJS).appendTo('body');
jQuery(cookieConsentInit).appendTo('body');
</script>
```

I have confirmed this works in the browser console but this does not work in Google Tag Manager because any JS code needs to be between <script> tags. So the <script> tags within the variable strings get interpreted despite being part of a string variable. See screenshot below.

[image]

I tried escaping the less-than and greater-than signs with the appropriate entity (i.e. &gt ;) but this also failed.

Comment: I'll advise against appending `cookieConsentInit` to the page. If it works in the first pace, it means it is the same as running eval in your code. If any third party can access your variables, they can append malicious code on your page. Why not run the code directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the cookie consent script when the parent script is loaded using the `onload` event. Here is an example:

```
var cookieConsentJS = document.createElement( 'script' );
cookieConsentJS.type = 'text/javascript';
cookieConsentJS.src = '/path/to/cookieconsent.min.js';
cookieConsentJS.setAttribute('data-cfasync', false); // not sure what this is, but not touching.

// this part of the code will run when the script is loaded. 
cookieConsentJS.onload = function() {
    // here is your code running outside of a string.
    window.cookieconsent.initialise({
        "palette":{
            "popup":{"background":"#000"},
            "button":{"background":"#f1d600"}
        }
    });
};

// now let's append your code to the body.
document.body.appendChild( cookieConsentJS );
```

Note that jQuery was not used in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Marked Ibu's answer as the final answer because his example using onload gave me an alternative approach that I was not aware of (running window.cookieconsent.initialise directly however did not work for some reason).

The exact solution, based on his example, is below:

```
var cookieConsentJS = document.createElement( 'script' );
cookieConsentJS.type = 'text/javascript';
cookieConsentJS.src = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cookieconsent@3/build/cookieconsent.min.js';
cookieConsentJS.setAttribute('data-cfasync', false); 

var cookieConsentInit = document.createElement( 'script' );
cookieConsentInit.innerText = 'window.cookieconsent.initialise({"palette":{"popup":{"background":"#000"},"button":{"background":"#f1d600"}}});';

cookieConsentJS.onload = function() {
    document.body.appendChild( cookieConsentInit );
};

document.body.appendChild( cookieConsentJS );
```

Comment: Instead of creating a script tag for `cookieConsentInit`, you can run the code directly.  No need to turn it into a string and then append it when you can run the js yourself. Plus it is more secure.

Comment: @Ibu In the context of Google Tag Manager, how would you ensure the code runs directly before the closing body tag without selecting that tag via jQuery and adding the code via a string? For organizational reasons I need to use Google Tag Manager.